# Whats the equivalent of this mongoid2 query in mongoid3?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I had this query in Mongoid2 that was working fine:

```
GlobalWord.collection.update({"_id" => "foo"}, {"$inc" => {:count => 1}}, :upsert => true)
```

If it finds the `GlobalWord` with the id `foo`, then it updates its count by one, otherwise it creates a document with the id `foo` and a count of one. I didn't find an equivalent for that in mongoid3.

edit: I need the query to be atomic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used
    GlobalWord.create(:id => word).inc(:count, 1)
which seems to be atomic

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
GlobalWord.find("_id": "foo").upsert("$inc": {count: 1})
```

I didn't test it, though. There's no MongoDB on my phone :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html#atomic) & [rdoc](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Query#upsert-instance_method)

`GlobalWord.new(id: word).upsert("$inc" => {count: 1})`